# What does "Your vote is now locked in" mean?

Tags: support

I down voted a question and tried to undo my down vote as it was not right. So I tried to undo my vote to which a box appeared and said

```
This question is voted 48 minutes ago. Your vote is locked in unless the question is edited
```

So does it mean I would not be able to vote unless the question is edited?

If I can vote again, when will be the time?

Does it apply to down votes only or up votes too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it says, your vote cannot be changed unless the question changes.  This is to stop people voting up and down all the time I guess.  If the question changes you have a chance to modify your original vote.  Yes, it applies to up and downvotes equally - and also applies to voting on answers.

FYI.  Stack-exchange functionality questions can be found on meta.stackoverflow.com.  For example this question has been asked and answered below:

[Is there a way to cancel the downvote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85398/is-there-a-way-to-cancel-the-downvote)

Comment: That meta post doesn't get into the *reason* but yes, it is to keep people from engaging in tactical down-voting where users down-vote other posts to push theirs to the top, giving it some sort of advantage in the early voting. Once you cast a vote, there is only a short period of time where you can change it... unless the post is edited.

Comment: @RobertCartaino - thanks for that clarification.  That makes a lot of sense, even if I am slightly surprised that people try to game the system like that.